# How can I suppress error messages and silently continue a GDB script?

Tags: gdb

I have a GDB script that is deadreckon'ing up the callstack and blindly calling `list` and `up` using gdb 7.2:

```
gdb -q -batch -x gdb.cmd
```

`gdb.cmd` has:

```
list
up-silently
list
up-silently
[...]
```

Unfortunately, this will fail if gdb can't find the source file or it is inside a library that wasn't compiled with `-g`:

```
gdb.cmd:30: Error in sourced command file:
Line number 63 out of range; /home/ross/tmp.cc has 62 lines.
```

How can I suppress all errors and continue executing the script even if `list` or any other command fails?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a good way from the gdb CLI.  The gdb CLI is rather limited.

If your gdb is built against Python, you can do it reasonably easily.  Search for the "ignore-errors" script.